# How to connect frontend and backend via tcp/ip?

Tags: c++, tcp, frontend, client-server, backend

I have a GUI (frontend, programmed in C++) and a kernel (backend, programmed in C++). Currently, the frontend is just linked to the backend library. However, due to performance reasons I want the functions from the library to be exceuted from another computer/server. The communication to the server shall be done via a TCP/IP connection.

The current idea to achieve this, is to set up a TCP/IP client/server connection. After the connection is set up the gui sends a header id and maybe additional data to the server, where the code is executed and the return is send back. However, to achieve this, I have to map every function to a header id and program the handling of the received data for every function in the backend. This is a tedious work, where I have to wrap each function manually.

The question is now: What is the common practice to connect the frontend to the backend via a server/client connection? And is there any generator (like SWIG for Python etc.) to generate a TCP/IP interface?

Comment: Background info for RPC:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call

Comment: I suggest you look into gRPC with protobuf messages. 
It is a fairly well-used way to define the interface with a meta-language and then generate the handling classes and functions.